# How do I embed CryptoSwift into WatchKit Extension target without build error?

Tags: encryption, ios10, watchkit, watchos-3, cryptoswift

I am trying to embed CryptoSwift as an embedded framework into a Watch app (watchOS3) - I would like to be able to use AES encryption and decryption from within the Watch app.

I start by creating a new clean Xcode project: watchOS application using "iOS App with WatchKit App" in a local git repository.

To add CryptSwift, I followed the installation guidance of CryptoSwift (https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift#installation) by adding it as a git submodule (`git submodule add https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift.git`) on the top level project folder. Then I dragged the `CryptoSwift.xcodeproj` into the clean Xcode project.

Then, I add the `CryptSwift.framework` into the Embedded Binaries of the iOS app target. Build was successful, and I could use `import CryptoSwift`, e.g., in `ViewController.swift`.

But when I add the CryptSwift.framework into the Embedded Binaries of the WatchKit Extension target. Hits Build, it fails: "`clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/brian/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestCrypto2-bkzbizyfkacuctdwdngnvcrrewpi/Build/Products/Debug-watchsimulator/CryptoSwift.framework/CryptoSwift'`". And I am not able to use `import CryptoSwift` in e.g. `InterfaceController.swift` in the WatchKit Extension.

I have tried a number of different approaches to add the `CryptoSwift.framework` to the WatchKit Extension, but none with success.

Does anyone know how to add this CryptoSwift framework to the WatchKit Extension the right way, if possible?

- Xcode 8.1 (8B62)
- iOS 10.1
- watchOS 3.1